# Configure Grafana datasource to use multiple ElasticSearch nodes

Tags: elasticsearch, grafana

In order to increase the availability of Grafana monitoring is there a way to configure multiple ElasticSearch nodes in one datasource and let Grafana 'load balance' between them, or configure explicit primary and failover nodes?

I'm using a 3-node ElasticSearch cluster to store monitoring data, however during a rolling update (or if a node fails) Grafana will error if it can't connect.  I have spread the config for different indexes across instances, however 1/3 of the dashboards will typically stop working if a node fails so its not ideal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to configure multiple elasticsearch nodes as a datasource on grafana, there is a [feature request](https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues/8170) for it but it was not implemented yet.

One way to solve this is to start another elasticsearch node configured only as a [coordinating node](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-node.html#coordinating-node) and then configure this node as the data source on grafana.